# Rails: has_and_belongs_to_many with "master" record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have to models: `User` and `Post`. Each user can "pin" (add to his page) any post, so `user.posts` should return all added posts and `post.users` should return all users which pined the post.

Also user should be able to create post, so each post has one creator ("master" user), so `post.user` should return this master user (post is always "pined" for master user).

My idea is to use migration like

```
create_table :posts_users do |t|
  t.references :post, null: false, index: true
  t.references :user, null: false, index: true
  t.boolean :master, null: false, default: false
end
```

But how should i specify associations in models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has_and_belongs_to_many` method is really just a shortcut for defining the `has_many through` relationship and it's not suitable for storing any additional data in the intermediate join table. Having renamed your `posts_users` to `pins`, I think it could work like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins
  has_many :posts, through: :pins

  has_many :master_posts, -> {where pins: {master: true}},
    class_name: "Post", through: :pins, source: :post
end

class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pins
  has_many :users, through: :pins

  def user
    users.where(pins: {master: true}).first
  end
end
```

Overall it's just the standard [`has_many :through association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) you will encounter in almost every app. The interesting part is the `master_posts` association. You can about the passed options in the [`documentation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) (see the `Options` part at the bottom).

```
bob = User.create! name: "Bob"

bob.posts.create! title: "Title 1"
bob.posts.create! title: "Title 2"

bob.posts.pluck :title
# => ["Title 1", "Title 2"]

bob.master_posts.create! title: "Title 3"
bob.master_posts.create! title: "Title 4"

bob.master_posts.pluck :title
# => ["Title 3", "Title 4"]

bob.master_posts.last.user == bob
# => true
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Also added `has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy` to both User and Post.

Comment: And also i think i can omit `class_name` in User.